# trying to fix form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i'll try to make form validation by giving the background colour and focus to each input when input is empty but, it turns out even though i fill the input, it still focus on the first input. It is not continue to check on the next input

I have tried with this code

```
    var fName=document.getElementById("in_fName");
    var lName=document.getElementById("in_lName");

//first name validation
        if (fName.innerHTML===""){
            alert("he");
            fName.style.background="#DE8971";
            fName.style.color="#FFE9D6";
            fName.focus();
        } else {
            alert("here");            
            fName.style.background="white";
            fName.style.color="black";
            return false;
        }

       //last name validation
       if (lName.innerHTML===""){
             lName.style.background="#DE8971";
             lName.style.color="#FFE9D6";
            lName.focus();
        }
```

Comment: It is most likely because you ```return false;``` if ```fName``` is not an empty string. Additionally to this, when working with inputs it would be recommended to use the ```.value``` method and not ```.innerHTML```.

Comment: You need to check the value of the input like fName.value

Comment: It works, after I changed with .value

Answer (score 0):

Why not use require fields in the html section. By doing that you will not have to check for validation in JavaScript.

It would be better if you could also share your html code.

Comment: I believe that may have been more useful as a comment rather than an answer.